# Using state of a custom hook in a componenent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I am working on a mini project of cart functionality, and I am creating a custom hook

```
useCart
```

That will contain my cart functionalities (add to cart etc), and a state [cart, setCart] to store the cart objects.

My custom hook is located in a /Hook folder, my Product is located in a /Component/Product folder

I want to use this state in my `Product.js` component, however, when i try to use it it tells me that cart is undefined (I tried to pass a simple string and it worked so i don't think it's a relative path issue)

I am a beginner, so i wanted to know, is there something wrong with my architecture ? How to pass this state to `Product.js` and update it ?

I read about context API but i am not sure about the syntax and if it's a good fit here...

Thanks guys.

Here are `Product.js` and `useCart.js`:

[Product.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiLxV.png)

[useCart.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBW1G.png)

Product :

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import useCart from '../../Hooks/useCart';
import Data from '../../local-json/products';

export default function Product() {

  const [products, setProducts] = useState();
  const {cart, setCart, addItem, removeItem} = useCart();

  useEffect(()=>{
    setProducts(Data);
  }, []);

  console.log(addItem);

  return (
    <>
      <article className="product-single">
        <h1>Fire sale !</h1>
        {
          Data.map(el =>{
            return(
              <h2>{el.productName}</h2>
            )
          })
        }

        <button>Add</button>
      </article>
    </>
  )
}
```

useCart :

```
    import React, {useState, useEffect, useContext} from 'react'

export default function useCart() {

    const [cart, setCart] = useState(); /* Here we store the product object */



    const addItem = (productObj) =>{
      setCart([...cart, productObj]);
    } /* Add to cart function */

    const removeItem = (productObj) => {
      setCart(cart.filter(
        item => {
          return item !== productObj;
        }
      ))
    } /* Remove from cart function */

    const quantitiyAdd = () => {

    } /* Add one item function */

    const quantityRemove = () => {

    } /* Remove one item function */
    
    return {cart, setCart, addItem, removeItem};
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the code in code format instead of the images. It is much easier to help you that way

Comment: Is cart an array of objects?

Answer (score 0):

Try to define a default value for your `cart` array, this should prevent the `undefined` error:

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
```

Anyway, if you want to declare and provide a global state through your application you should look into the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your hook structure seems to be ok, but there might be an issue with the way you set are use your cart data.

```
    const [cart, setCart] = useState([]); /* Cart is an empty array */


 const addItem = (productObj) =>{
//Do not add cart directly to setCart, you may get stale data. 
//prevState is your current status before the update
      setCart((prevState) => [...prevState, productObj]);
    } /* Add to cart function */
```

Answer (score -1):

It was indeed because there was no value in cart, i feel stupid haha but it works now. Thanks !

I will dive in context API might be useful thanks guys you rock !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).